# How to change applications icons of Kde-Plasma 5

Tags: kubuntu, icons, kde, kde5, plasma-5

I'm using

```
Kubuntu 16.04
KDE Plasma version 5.5.5
```

In my applications I have these enormous icons. Eg., from Dolphin:

[image]

Which I cannot change. I tried "System Settings"-> changing everything in "Appearance", except the theme that remains Breeze because I couldn't find any other. But these icons remain the same. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had previously had Gnome installed. So this strange behavior was in fact caused by applications picking up a GTK theme.

I was able to change GTK theme in **Settings > Application Style > Gnome Application Style (GTK)**.

After that, I unset `QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME` from `/etc/profile.d/appmenu-qt5.sh` and was finally able to change icons from  **Settings > Icons**