# Help with finding Ubuntu flavor or desktop shown in screenshot?

Tags: desktop-environments, distro-recommendation

Can someone please help me find out which desktop this is?

[image: screenshot of desktop in question]

I found it in an answer to this question:
[What software can I use to view epub documents?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14378/what-software-can-i-use-to-view-epub-documents)

Comment: I don't think you can say. You can install almost any Desktop Environment on any Distro. And this looks like some modified KDE(?) + Plank or so

Comment: You could ask them in the comment section what desktop they're using.

Comment: @mchid I would...but i don't have enough reputation :(

Comment: I asked for you... But not sure if @Bapi is still active, last post from June last year

Comment: @pLumo Wow, thank you so much!

Comment: I am pretty sure that this is just a theme. It *does* look like KDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a themed KDE desktop.

The dock looks like `plank` and the [icon pack used is *La Capitaine*](https://github.com/keeferrourke/la-capitaine-icon-theme).

---

##### the desktop environment:

As an official Ubuntu flavour or distro, you can install [Kubuntu](https://kubuntu.org/getkubuntu/) which uses the KDE plasma desktop.

Alternatively, you can install the KDE (plasma) desktop on an existing system by running the following commands (note: this will most likely change all of your defaults like your display manager and splash screen theme, default theme, etc):

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install kubuntu-full
```

However, it is possible that [KDE will still pick up some GTK themes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/885368/how-to-change-applications-icons-of-kde-plasma-5?rq=1) from Gnome if you install this on an existing, standard, Gnome-based Ubuntu system.

---

##### icon theme and dock:

Next, you can install plank by running the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install plank
```

Finally, you can install the icon pack by running the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git
mkdir ~/.icons
cd ~/.icons
git clone https://github.com/keeferrourke/la-capitaine-icon-theme.git
```

You will still have to select your icon theme through the KDE deksotp settings.

Comment: It should be noted that they moved the dash bar from the bottom to the top. This should be pretty easy to do but if you have trouble, just ask another question.

Comment: Additionally, they enabled the global menu to show File, Edit, View, Go, Help on the dash instead of the menu bar on the window so this might be something you'll have to look up as well.

Comment: I think there is an additional "active window control" widget or something of the sort. In addition, I think the dock is the Latte dock. I haven't had the time to experiment with all of this, but it's been really helpful. 
thanks